# How can I replace a column of values by another with different number of rows?

Tags: pandas

I have the following df:

```
df=
               A     B    C
2016-04-16     3     2    2 
2016-04-17     4     4    1 
2016-04-18     7     3    1
2016-04-19     5     1    3
2016-04-20     5     1    7
```

On the other hand I have a recalculated column (with 4 rows instead of 5):

```
df1=
                C
2016-04-16     3.2 
2016-04-17     4.7 
2016-04-18     7.1
2016-04-19     3.3
```

how could I replace the recalculated column into the original `df` to obtain the following output?

```
df=
               A     B    C
2016-04-16     3     2    3.2
2016-04-17     4     4    4.7
2016-04-18     7     3    7.1
2016-04-19     5     1    3.3
2016-04-20     5     1    7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `combine_first`

```
In [1327]: df.assign(C=df1.C.combine_first(df.C))
Out[1327]:
            A  B    C
2016-04-16  3  2  3.2
2016-04-17  4  4  4.7
2016-04-18  7  3  7.1
2016-04-19  5  1  3.3
2016-04-20  5  1  7.0
```

Or,

```
In [1331]: df1.combine_first(df)
Out[1331]:
              A    B    C
2016-04-16  3.0  2.0  3.2
2016-04-17  4.0  4.0  4.7
2016-04-18  7.0  3.0  7.1
2016-04-19  5.0  1.0  3.3
2016-04-20  5.0  1.0  7.0
```